# How can I check if a Hashtable values are all 0?

Tags: c#, hashtable, cycle

This is my code :

```
Hashtable actualValues = new Hashtable();
actualValues.Add("Field1", Int32.Parse(field1.Value));
actualValues.Add("Field2", Int32.Parse(field2.Value));
actualValues.Add("Field3", Int32.Parse(field3.Value));

bool isAllZero = true;
foreach (int actualValue in actualValues)
{
    if (actualValue > 1)
        isAllZero = false;
}
if (isAllZero)
{

}
```

but I get this exception `System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.` on Line 6, close to `foreach`.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: what is the Type of 'actualValues'?

Comment: Please show the declaration of `actualValues`

Comment: (string, int) , you can see in the code!

Comment: what line do you get the exception?

Comment: on which line is the exception thrown?

Comment: did you try to save values in the table as strings, and then in the foreach loop cast them to int?

Comment: If you want to keep using the foreach loop you should break as soon as you set isAllZero to false...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hashtable returns returns an IEnumerator of type `IDictionaryEnumerator`, the elements returned by the MoveNext method are of type `DictionaryEntry`, not int - your foreach loop is invalid.

Try the following:

```
bool isAllZero = actualValues.Values.Cast<int>().All(v => v == 0);
```

Or without Linq:

```
bool isAllZero = true;
foreach (int actualValue in actualValues.Values)
{
  if (actualValue != 0) 
  {
    isAllZero = false;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I get ICollection doesnt contain definition of All()... ! It doesnt works :(

Comment: @markzzz Have you included a using to pull in the `System.Linq` namespace and included the call to `Cast<int>`?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you can use Linq

```
bool isAllZero = Hashtable.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().All(pair => (int)pair.Value == 0);
```

And if you replace the `HashTable` with a `Dictionary<string, int>`, it becomes

```
bool isAllZero = dictionary.All(pair => pair.Value == 0);
```

Comment: hash tables return a `DictionaryEntry`

Comment: @DanielA.White Thanks for spotting this.

Comment: also you will have to cast the `Value`.

Comment: Hashtable doesnt contain definition of Cast :(

Comment: @DanielA.White Doh! (I haven't used HashTables in years...)

Comment: @markzzz The first line is equivalent to 'Assuming you use .net>= 3.5'

Comment: @markzzz BTW, if you use .net>=2.0, you might consider using Dictionary instead of HashTable

Comment: @markzzz Add -->using System.Linq;<-- to your using clause at the top of the source

Comment: @markzzz ...And consider using a Dictionary<string, int> instead of HashTable :)

Comment: Why Dictionary and not Hashtable?

Comment: @markzzz Generic dictionaries are strongly typed which allows detecting a lot of errors at compile time. Additionally, they implement a strongly typed IEnumerable which allows writing the second block of code in my answer (shorter... no?)

Answer (score 3):

When you loop over a hash table you get a `DictionaryEntry`, not an `int`.

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in actualValues)
{
    if (((int)entry.Value) > 1)
        isAllZero = false;
}
```

Comment: from the semantic of `isAllZero` the comparison should probably be done with `>=` - but that's just a guess